# PDF for the square of a multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I have a vector of random variables $\mathbf{X}$ whose pdf is given by a multivariate Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$. What is the pdf for the joint distribution of the element-wise square of the random variable, i.e. $\mathbf{X}\odot\mathbf{X}$, where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with  formulas for its characteristic or moment generating functions?

Comment: Moment generating function might work.